# Run Angular2 and Spring Boot Project on tomcat7

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, spring-boot, angular2-template, angular2-directives

i've developed two separated projects the first one is web dynamic project which his structure giving by eclipse and the second one is an angular-2 project.
so in my case, i tried to merge the two projects to be runned on the same server `Tomcat7` but at least my index page only load standard content, no angular staff appear with my page.
so please any one can provide me what is the best way to make angular2 and spring project to be runned together.
Note: i used `eclipse kepler` as my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I made a presentation at DevoxxUS where I generated an Angular app and then deployed it under Spring Boot. You can watch it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8r76d8QzXs